# PhP Error; Trying To Print To Console

Tags: javascript, php

**Specific Problem:**

```
echo '<script>console.log("Error creating table: " . $conn->error)</script>';
```

**Error In Console:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
```

[image]

Please let me know if you have alternative ways of printing out to console in php.

Comment: `echo '<script>console.log("Error creating table: " '. $conn->error.')</script>';`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: JavaScript knows nothing about PHP operators and variables. Not only PHP and JavaScript are different languages; they also typically run on different computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to terminate the string.

```
echo '<script>console.log("Error creating table: ' . $conn->error . '")</script>';
```

Variables are only evaluated in strings enclosed in double quotes (`"`). If you use single quotes (`'`) you have to concatenate them yourself with the dot (`.`) operator.

EDIT: I put the double quote on the wrong side of the variable.

Comment: I now get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: I updated my answer. `echo '<script>console.log("Error creating table: ' . $conn->error . '")</script>';`

Comment: `str_replace(['"', "\n"], ['\"', '\n'], $conn->error)`